# History of connected servers/clients to a SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sp-who2

Is there a way in SQL Server to see the history of all connected servers / clients with their respected hostnames, IP addresses and the last connected date?

Basically what I want is an history table of the `sp_who2` stored procedure.

Does this or something similar exist by default, so that I can retrieve the above mentioned info?

Comment: No, such a thing does not exist. It is easily constructed with a [logon trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/triggers/logon-triggers), but there's nothing out of the box.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. 
I expected it already but was hopeful nonetheless

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution if you can utilize a trigger.

If you run this script, subsequently each time there is a login, details of that logic event will be logged to [master].[dbo].[TRACETABLE].

```
CREATE TABLE [master].[dbo].[TRACETABLE] ( 
[EVENTDATE]                DATETIME                         NOT NULL,
[DBNAME]                   NVARCHAR(128)                        NULL,
[CURRENTUSER]              NVARCHAR(128)                        NULL,
[HOSTNAME]                 NVARCHAR(128)                        NULL,
[APPLICATIONNAME]          NVARCHAR(128)                        NULL,
[PROCEDURENAME]            NVARCHAR(128)                        NULL,
[USERID]                   SMALLINT                             NULL,
[USERNAME]                 NVARCHAR(128)                        NULL,
[SUSERID]                  INT                                  NULL,
[SUSERNAME]                NVARCHAR(128)                        NULL,
[IS_SERVERADMIN_SYSADMIN]  INT                                  NULL,
[IS_DB_OWNER]              INT                                  NULL,
[IS_DDL_ADMIN]             INT                                  NULL,
[IS_DB_DATAREADER]         INT                                  NULL,
[ORIGINAL_LOGIN]           NVARCHAR(4000)                       NULL,
[NET_TRANSPORT]            SQL_VARIANT                          NULL,
[PROTOCOL_TYPE]            SQL_VARIANT                          NULL,
[AUTH_SCHEME]              SQL_VARIANT                          NULL,
[LOCAL_NET_ADDRESS]        SQL_VARIANT                          NULL,
[LOCAL_TCP_PORT]           SQL_VARIANT                          NULL,
[CLIENT_NET_ADDRESS]       SQL_VARIANT                          NULL,
[PHYSICAL_NET_TRANSPORT]   SQL_VARIANT                          NULL)

GO
GRANT INSERT ON [master].[dbo].[TRACETABLE] TO PUBLIC
GRANT SELECT on [master].[sys].[dm_exec_connections]
GO
CREATE TRIGGER Logon_Trigger_Track_IP
ON ALL SERVER FOR LOGON
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO [master].[dbo].[TRACETABLE]
   --the auditing snippet below works fine in a 
  --login trigger, 
  --database trigger 
  --or any stored procedure.
  SELECT 
    getdate()                                    AS EventDate,
    DB_NAME()                                    AS DBName,
    CURRENT_USER                                 AS CurrentUser,
    HOST_NAME()                                  AS HostName,
    APP_NAME()                                   AS ApplicationName,
    OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID)                        AS ProcedureName,
    USER_ID()                                    AS Userid,
    USER_NAME()                                  AS UserName,
    SUSER_ID()                                   AS sUserid,
    SUSER_SNAME()                                AS sUserName,
    IS_SRVROLEMEMBER ('sysadmin')                AS [Is_ServerAdmin_Sysadmin],
    IS_MEMBER('db_owner')                        AS [Is_DB_owner],
    IS_MEMBER('db_ddladmin')                     AS [Is_DDL_Admin],
    IS_MEMBER('db_datareader')                   AS [Is_DB_Datareader],
    ORIGINAL_LOGIN()                             AS [ORIGINAL_LOGIN],
    ConnectionProperty('net_transport')          AS 'net_transport', 
    ConnectionProperty('protocol_type')          AS 'protocol_type',
    ConnectionProperty('auth_scheme')            AS 'auth_scheme',
    ConnectionProperty('local_net_address')      AS 'local_net_address',
    ConnectionProperty('local_tcp_port')         AS 'local_tcp_port',
    ConnectionProperty('client_net_address')     AS 'client_net_address',
    ConnectionProperty('physical_net_transport') AS 'physical_net_transport'

  END
GO
ENABLE TRIGGER [Logon_Trigger_Track_IP] ON ALL SERVER
```